# Cypress run test from CLI

Tags: npm, cypress

I am getting `reference error` while running code from CLI in cypress

Tried to update the node module but no luck

> `ReferenceError: passes is not defined
>       at Spec.Base.epilogue (/Users/msgai/aistudio/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:324:31)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
>       at Runner.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Reporter.emit (/Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js:237:55)
>       at Object.server.startWebsockets.onMocha (/Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/project.js:300:22)
>       at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/socket.js:236:36)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at /Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/socket/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)`
>
> `ReferenceError: passes is not defined
>       at Spec.Base.epilogue (/Users/msgai/aistudio/node_modules/mocha/lib/reporters/base.js:324:31)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
>       at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
>       at Runner.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Reporter.emit (/Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/reporter.js:237:55)
>       at Object.server.startWebsockets.onMocha (/Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/project.js:300:22)
>       at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/lib/socket.js:236:36)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at /Users/keshavsharma/Library/Caches/Cypress/3.4.1/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/socket/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)`

Comment: does is run headful? Or isn't the CLI-run unrelated?

Comment: Usually, that happens because you have a problem with your reporters' configuration. Can you show us your `cypress.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like you are using:
1. Cypress 3.4.1
2. Mocha version (not clear)

I would suggest:
1. try finding Mocha version installed and upgrade to 6(if its v<6):
npm i mocha
2. try finding cypress-multi-reporters version installed and install(if not already):
npm i cypress-multi-reporters

Let me know if it fixes the issue.